# pass list of JSON blobs to django template

Tags: python, django, json, serialization, python-2.7

How do I pass a python list of JSON blobs to a django template so i can parse it from JSON into a javascript object?

With jquery I have tried the likes of `$.parseJSON('{{list_of_JSON_blobs|escapejs}}')` in the template, but the "string representation" of a python list is causing syntax errors.

Doing `json.dumps(list_of_JSON_blobs)` doesn't work either as it stringfys the already serialised JSON blobs.

Currently I am doing `dumps( [loads(blob) for blob in list_of_JSON_blobs])` but this is obviously not the optimal method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked it out:

use `join`, and encapsulate the resulting string in paren

```
'[' + ','.join(list_of_JSON_blobs) + ']'
```